# Is "soul-to-soul talk" a common expression in English?

Tags: expressions

Is "soul-to-soul talk" a common expression in English for describing a sincere talk between two people? Or is it not common at all?

Comment: No; we use *heart-to-heart talk*.

Comment: 'Soul-baring' might also be used, 'soul baring talk' and 'mutual soul-baring' get a few hits,"soul-baring conversation" gets more than "soul to soul talk". .

Comment: If someone requested to have a "soul-to-soul talk" then I would immediately expect it to be of religious nature.

Comment: If this is regards to males having a male-centric talk then [man-to-man](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/man-to-man) is acceptable especially if it is to solve a dispute.

Comment: I'm curious which language uses "soul-to-soul".

Comment: My friends and I have used "soul-to-soul" when we are talking about our personal stories and experience with spiritual faith. It's not a very common topic for most people though

Comment: @Dancrumb Russian, for example: [*разговор по душам*](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/разговор%20по%20душам) literally means "soul-to-soul talk".

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The common English expression is "heart-to-heart talk", or even just "a heart-to-heart".

Other similar expressions, like "soul-to-soul", while not common, would probably be understood as a reference to or variation of "heart-to-heart".

Comment: Google [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heart+to+heart+talk%2Csoul+to+soul+talk&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheart%20to%20heart%20talk%3B%2Cc0) backs you up

Comment: @Kevin I think [this link](http://goo.gl/yKEHMq) compares the usage of the two phrases more clearly

Comment: @costrom why? OP specifically asked for "soul to soul *talk*"  why omit the talk?

Comment: Further googling ""soul to soul" meaning" gets you nothing about any kind of talk or conversation, whereas googling ""heart to heart" meaning" gets you exactly what OP is looking for

Comment: @Kevin it supports BradC's claim that "soul to soul", while uncommon compared to "heart to heart", is used, and could potentially be understood by an English speaker

Comment: Yeah, that's all I meant, that while "soul to soul talk" isn't something a native speaker would use, it's also not likely to be misunderstood (unless perhaps the listener assigns a religious meaning, but that would depend on context).

Comment: I think if I heard the phrase *said aloud* I might actually hear ***sole-to-sole***; I'm picturing two people sitting on the floor across from one another, feet stretched out in front of them, or some under-the-table footsie. I'm sure I'd figure out what was actually meant almost immediately, but I'd still have that image. I'd avoid *soul-to-soul* in speech for that reason, absent any compelling need for this specific language (or a dialect that makes a really clear distinction in pronunciation).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will be understood as a variant of "heart-to-heart," but it might come across as more intense than was intended.

Answer (score 4):

A phrase that comes to mind to use for "soul to soul" is "personal, deep and meaningful", which I first heard in the 1980's.

Google [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=personal+deep%2Cdeep+and+meaningful%2Cpersonal+deep+and+meaningful&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpersonal%20deep%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeep%20and%20meaningful%3B%2Cc0) doesn't find "personal deep and meaningful" as a complete phrase, but does show a rise in usage of "deep and meaningful" continuing from about 1920 to the present.

Hence "Personal, deep and meaningful" is probably tautological to some degree, with "deep and meaningful" more often used on its own:

> To have deep and meaningful conversations is to talk about mental and spiritual things. {[mindreality.com](http://www.mindreality.com/deep-and-meaningful-conversations)}
>
> Used to describe a conversation of great emotion (usually, but not exclusively describes a conversation of a sad nature). {[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Deep%20%26%20Meaningful)}

However, if the purpose of the conversation is to attempt to reconcile a point of contention between two people, "heart to heart" would be more idiomatic, as for example in "I think you and I need to have a heart to heart (talk) about this".

Comment: When I was a teenager in 1980s Australia, the term "D&M" referred to a deep & meaningful conversation, usually with angsty romantic connotations.

Comment: @Jeremy I heard it as "P.D.&M.", also in Australia. It was in common enough usage to be abbreviated and remain widely understood.